# Why is ferret giving me error that the region is not 2D while plotting

Tags: reanalysis, era

I have downloaded ERA5 data and am trying to plot temperature variable. The problem I am facing is that even after providing a 2D area for plotting, ferret is giving an error saying that the region must be 2D

```
yes? fill t[k=1,l=1]
 **ERROR: dimensions improperly specified: must be a 2D region
      CONTOUR/FILL t[k=1,l=1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax

```
yes? fill 't'[k=1,l=1]
```

This is because ferret treats t variable name as time and to distinguish your variable name (if it is the same in the file), you have to provide it in double quotes.